# Validate currency and numerical input using jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

need some help here..
1) I need to validate an input field to check that it contains only numeric values. 
2) However, if user enters the $ in front, i need to remove the $ sign and still be able to validate if it is a valid input (eg $999 and 999 are both valid inputs but 99rt9 is not)
3) How can i validate this with jquery without using regular expression?

note: for the numeric validation part, I am using isNaN(). However, a $ in the input will cause this to become invalid..

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this by checking if the first char is a `$` and the next chars (without the doller sign) form a valid number.

```js
// keep a reference for the input.
let inp = $('#currency');

// add event : change this to your wanted one, I just used 'blur' for this example.
inp.on('blur', () => {
  // get the input's value trimmed.
  let val = $.trim(inp.val());
  if (val.length) {
    // checking
    if ((val.indexOf('$') === 0 && !isNaN(val.slice(1)) && val.length > 1) || !isNaN(val)) console.log('"' + val + '"' + ' is OK !');
    else console.log('"' + val + '"' + ' is NOT OK !');
  } else console.log('"' + val + '"' + ' is NOT OK !');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="currency" placeholder="enter a value and click outside to see the result" />
```

**Useful links :**

> jQuery's [`trim`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) function: it removes the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.
>   Javascript built-in [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) function: extracts a section of a string.

Hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score 0):

If you could use regex, you could use the following as your validating function:

```
function isValid(el) {
   return el.match(/^\$?\d+$/);
}
```

But since you can't, here are a couple of alternative implementations. Key thing is that I used `parseInt` instead of `isNaN` because there are corner cases: for instance, `12e1` is a valid number in scientific notation and thus, *it is* a number, and then used [coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using) to check that you get the same value back.

The first option validates as-you-type, and this should be enough.

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(evt) {
  if ($('.currency.error', this).length) { // If there are failed fields
    evt.preventDefault(); // Prevent submission   
  }
});

$('.currency').on('input', function() {
  if (!isValid(this.value.trim())) {
    this.classList.add('error'); // Add error 
  } else {
    this.classList.remove('error'); // Remove if it became valid
  }
});

function isValid(el) {
  el = el.charAt(0) == '$' ? el.slice(1) : el; // A dollar sign at the beginning is ok
  return parseInt(el) == el;

}
```

```css
.error {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="currency" />
  <input type="text" class="currency" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The second one does the validation only on submission. This might be more robust for your case, since it'll prevent submission of empty fields:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(evt) {
  $fields = $('.currency', this); // Limit field search to the form
  $fields.removeClass('error'); // Remove all error classes

  let $errors = $fields.filter(function() {
    return !isValid(this.value.trim())
  });

  if ($errors.length) { // If there are failed fields
    evt.preventDefault(); // Prevent submission
    $errors.addClass('error'); // Mark as failed
  }
});

function isValid(el) {
  el = el.charAt(0) == '$' ? el.slice(1) : el; // A dollar sign at the beginning is ok
  return parseInt(el) == el;
}
```

```css
.error {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="currency" />
  <input type="text" class="currency" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```